# Can't remote debug node running in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

[Github link](https://github.com/GuyMichaely/fiction-forge)

I'm trying to debug my backend node server running inside a docker container. For the life of me I can't seem to remote debug the node process when it's running in docker. I used `netstat -an` to verify that ports 9229 are open in both my host machine and in the container, and I made sure to map the port 9229 on my host machine to 9229 in the container. I'm running node with `nodemon --inspect --trace-warnings --unhandled-rejections=strict server.js` but have also tried `node --inspect server.js` without success.

I've tried multiple vscode [launch.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GuyMichaely/fiction-forge/master/.vscode/launch.json) configurations, none of which have worked.

- The first config is the default one and does not attempt to attach to a running node process.
- The second fails with the error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '~/Desktop/fiction-forge/package.json'`. I don't know why the docker extension is looking for `package.json` in `~/Desktop/fiction-forge`.
- The third seems to try to connect, giving a loading animation in vscode, but ultimately fails. I've also tried the remote debugger in Chrome to no avail.

I *am* able to remote debug the node process with the chrome remote debugger when I run it on my host machine on port 9229. It remains a mystery to me why, if the ports are opened and mapped correctly, there is a difference when node is running in the container.

You can create the image and run the container with `docker build -t fiction-forge . && docker run -p 3000:3000 -p 5000:5000 -p 9229:9229 fiction-forge`. Then start the server with `docker exec <container-name> npm run dev --prefix server`.

Answer (score 0):

Running node with `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` and specifying 127.0.0.1:9229 as a connection in the chrome devtools worked.